# How to prepare a windows vm so that it`s os disk can be used to provision other vms

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am using create_option as from_image to create new vm and passing the old vhd url in it but it is not successfully provisioned.

What steps i need to follow to make it work ?

My vm is in azure from whose os disk i want to create new vms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to sysprep and generalize your VM and capture an image to use to deploy new VMs.

Follow the documentation located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource